# how to add checkmark in tableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkbox, cell, checkmark

I'm trying to show checkmark on tableview cell, but the checkmark appears only sometimes and it disappears when I scroll.

Below the code:

```html
 
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("vvxxx12", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    
        // Configure the cell...
        
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row] as? String //in dataArray values are stored
             

       if dataArray.containsObject(indexPath)
       {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
       }
       else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
       return cell
         }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
                    cell.accessoryType = .None
                   
                } else {
                    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                   
                }
            }    
        }
```

Comment: Just checkout my given code, Its work correctly. if its work for you please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Checkout new code given in snaps

Comment: @Pavan  i had question arise when i have to select only one item by checkmark how can i do that  and previous checkmark get remove so please  help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do following changes in your code to maintain checkmark into tableview while you are scrolling tableview

[image]

Result :

[image]

Its work fine now, Any problem let me know i will definitely help you to out.Enjoy..

Comment: thanks but in tableviewdidselect method when i write cell.accessoeyType it showing me error i.e unresolve identifier is used ,also i, add object and remove object  method but it showing that array has no such memer

Comment: Sorry i was used wrong logic.  I send u code snaps so you can just followed given code and i run and check this its work fine.

Comment: i had question arise when i have to select only one item by checkmark how can i do that and previous checkmark get remove so please help me

Comment: So you can do with them in diddeselect method

Comment: you have to checked that array count > 1 then u have to remove all values from array and simply add that selected cells unique value as i did previously

Comment: now simple logic that array contains only one everytime so in cellforrow its shows only selected indexpath value as checkmark

Comment: thanks  in between two values i have to select only one if i select first value then second get automatically unmark

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 following worked for me to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourtableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourtableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row] as? String
```

This suggests that `dataArray` contains strings.

```
if dataArray.containsObject(indexPath)
```

This suggests that `dataArray` contains index paths. Both of these should not be true. One array for data makes sense, and another one for selected rows or rows to be checked also makes sense, but not the same array for both.

What's probably happening is:

- Row selected - cell is then updated to have the checkmark accessory
- Table scrolled and cellForRowAtIndexPath is called - at no point will `dataArray` contain an index path, so the accessory is always cleared.

You need to be updating your model when a row is selected, to store the index path of the selected row, or update a selected flag on your model objects.